# MsBuild - Publishing a sub-folder rather than the root web web site

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I have a project, ReactJs using various libs and Grunt to build to JS and CSS.

There is a build folder which is the target of the grunt build

```
/
/bin
/build/ (with sub dirs -the files needed to be deployed)
/config
/src
...
[other files]
+ web.config
```

I'm trying to work out how to publish via web deploy just the

```
/bin
[contents of build]
web.config
```

I've seen various articles covering including files outside of the project, but wondered whether there is an easy way of specifying these files if inside the project directory?

TIA